# How do we use of NSSelectorFromString in swift?

Tags: swift

I do not understand why this always fails. Any help?
Apparently, I do n'o understand how **NSStringFromSelector** works?
Here is my code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("test(value:value2:)")
        if self.responds(to: selector) {
            print("it works")
        } else {
            print("it failed")
        }
    }

    func test(value: Int, value2: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you are discouraged from using *objective-c-ish* `NSStringFromSelector` in Swift. There are better (and safer) solutions like protocols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of your Selector string is wrong.  The Selector string for `NSSelectorFromString` has to look like the Objective-C signature.

Try:

```
let selector = NSSelectorFromString("testWithValue:value2:")
```

and your `func` has to be marked with `@objc` **or** your `class` has to be marked with `@objcMembers`.

---

**How to get the Selector string:**

Note: The preferred way to create a Selector in Swift is to use `#selector` as described by @DavidBerry in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012903/1630618) because it gives you compile-time checking of the Selector.

If you still need `NSSelectorFromString` then this is how to find out the string:

After adding `@objc` to your function and compiling the project, click on the **Related Items** icon in Xcode in the upper left of the `ViewController.swift` window and select **Generated Interface -> `<ProjectName>-Swift.h`**.  In there you will find your `func`'s Objective-C interface:

```
- (void)testWithValue:(NSInteger)value value2:(NSInteger)value2;
```

then concatenate the parts that end with colons to create the Selector string: `"testWithValue:value2:"`

Comment: Shouldn't the first "Value" is lower case?

Comment: @MintCamel, no.  The Objective-C version of the function takes the first parameter name, capitalizes it and adds WithParametername to the function name.  If you follow my directions above for finding the Objective-C version of the name in the generated header, you will see that it is `testWithValue:value2:`.  Using `NSSelectorFromString` isn't really the way to do it in Swift though.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues, first, for `NSSelectorFromString` to work, the method itself, as well as the class should be declared `@objc`  Second, the preferred way of doing this would be to use `#selector` which would give you compile-time checking of the validity of the selector.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.responds(to: #selector(test(value:value2:))) {
            print("it works")
        } else {
            print("it failed")
        }
    }

    @objc
    func test(value: Int, value2: Int) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `#selector` instead

```
let selector = #selector(test(value:value2:))
```

and make your function declaration with `@objc`

```
@objc func test(value: Int, value2: Int) {

}
```

Comment: unfortunately i have to use NSSelectorFromString and not #selector in this case