# How do I convert objective-c `sortedArrayUsingSelector:NSSelectorFromString` to swift?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, swift, selector

I trying to convert objective-c`code to`swift`and got stuck on this line of`objective-c` code:

```
NSArray *array = [[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts] sortedArrayUsingSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"string:")];
```

I try to do something similar using `swift`:

```
var array = InternalContactsHandler.sharedBuffer()?.contacts()?.sorted(by: NSSelectorFromString("string"))
```

but I get the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Selector' to expected argument type '(Any, Any) throws -> Bool'`

Not sure what it wants me to throw or how to write it properly in code. Any ideas?

***Edit*** 
Trying to use the `#selector` code produce the same result:

```
var tempData = InternalContactsHandler.sharedBuffer()?.contacts()?.sorted( by: #selector(Contact.nameOfContactCompare:))
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Selector' to expected argument type '(Any, Any) throws -> Bool'

`Contacts.nameOfContactCompare` is in `objective-C` and looks like this:

```
-(NSComparisonResult)nameOfContactCompare:(Contact*)c{

    NSString *f1 = [firstName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *l1 = [lastName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSString *f2 = [c.firstName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *l2 = [c.lastName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if (ABPersonGetSortOrdering() == kABPersonSortByFirstName) {
        return [self sortPrio1contact1:f1 prio2c1:l1 prio3c1:company prio1c2:f2 prio2c2:l2 prio3c2:c.company];
    } else {
        return [self sortPrio1contact1:l1 prio2c1:f1 prio3c1:company prio1c2:l2 prio2c2:f2 prio3c2:c.company];
    }
}
```

I have added the function in the `.h` file like this so that it can be used in `swift`:

```
-(NSComparisonResult)nameOfContactCompare:(Contact*)c;
```

The old `objective-c` code works:

```
NSArray *array = [[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts] sortedArrayUsingSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"nameOfContactCompare")];
```

Why not for swift?

Comment: the sorted function take element not NSSelectorFromString, you need to check what exactly your sortedArrayUsingSelector retunring.

Comment: can share what is inside contacts array and whats the output in case of objective c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223058/how-to-sort-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your array by property like this:

```
yourArray = yourArray.sort({ $0.yourString.lowercased() < $1.yourString.lowercased() })
```

The .lowercased() is to make sure that case sensitive won't be considered.

Comment: OK, with a bit of tinkering it worked with this: `let tempData = InternalContactsHandler.sharedBuffer()?.contacts().sorted(by: {($0 as! Contact).lastName.lowercased() < ($1 as! Contact).lastName.lowercased()})` Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to know! No problem.

Answer (score 1):

replace `NSSelectorFromString("string")` with `#selector(string)` or `#selector(SomeClass.string)`

[How do we use of NSSelectorFromString in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012799/how-do-we-use-of-nsselectorfromstring-in-swift)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Your solution seems like the right one. But for some reason I get the same error. Please take a look at the edited part of my question.

Comment: Because function has to take 2 arguments (prev and next contact), compare them and return Bool value

Comment: hm, but in a selector you don't pass any arguments. Care to elaborate a bit with an example in your answer. Would be very kind of you :)